# Facebook App Authenticate

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, oauth-2.0

Im using Manuel Lemos's **OAuth 2.0** PHP library, recently I removed my application from https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications and now when i tried to authorized my application, I'm getting this error.

> **OAuth client error**
>
> Error: it was not possible to access the API call: it was returned an
>   unexpected response status 400 Response: {"error":{"message":"Error
>   validating access token: User 123456 has not authorized
>   application
>   987654321.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"error_subcode":458}}

Does any one know how to re-authenticate my app ?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. It is just a **cookie** issue. Huh... Thanks GOD. (y)